# Checking if a CDN file is available

Tags: php

I have the following code working on a WordPress plugin. But there's no WP issue, the matter is:
*can I trust **`@get_headers`** to perform most of times?*

```
public function enqueue()
{
    $http = is_ssl() ? 'https:' : 'http:';
    $url = "$http//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.csss";
    if( $this->get_http_response_code( $url ) ) {
        my_load_external_script();
    }
    else {
        my_load_local_script();
    }
}

/**
 * Problem with getting header, return false
 *
 * otherwise return if headers are 200 or not
 *
 * @param  $url     string
 * @return boolean
 */
private function get_http_response_code( $url ) 
{
    $headers = @get_headers( $url );
    if( !$headers )
        return false;

    return substr( $headers[0], 9, 3 ) === '200';
 }
```

The current requirement for running WordPress is PHP 5.2.4 or greater. As I understand it, there's no 100% guarantee, but for having a plugin running in the wild I'd prefer the less problematic path. I've checked the following Stack Overflow Q&A's, but haven't come to any conclusion:

- [get_headers is throwing a warning instead of just returning false?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17154458/1287812)
- [Can I try/catch a warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1241728/1287812)

Comment: Hitting another server on a page request just to check if the CDN is available seems like bad design to me. I would do this check client side in javascript, and if the file is 404 then fallback to an alternate URL. Or make it a configured option of which URL to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience *no*, using `curl` is much better an reliable. I use the following code in one of my projects, this always works (and allows redirects, if you don't want to set `CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS` to `0`).

```
<?php

/**
 * Check if the URL is reachable.
 *
 * @param string $url
 *   The URL to check.
 * @return this
 * @throws \LogicException
 */
public function checkReachability($url) {
  $ch = curl_init($url);
  curl_setopt_array($ch, [
    CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 5,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 1,
    CURLOPT_NOBODY         => true,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 5,
    // It's very important to let other webmasters know who's probing their servers.
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; StackOverflow/0.0.1; +https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)",
  ]);
  curl_exec($ch);
  $code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
  curl_close($ch);
  if ($code !== 200) {
    throw new LogicException("The URL doesn’t exists (more specifically isn’t reachable).");
  }
  return $this;
}

?>
```

Of course you have the problem that you don't always have `curl` available, a fallback would be.

```
<?php

// PHP 5.3+
stream_context_set_default(array("http" => array(
  "method"     => "HEAD",
  "user_agent" => "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; StackOverflow/0.0.1; +https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)",
)));

set_error_handler(function ($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline ) {
  throw new LogicException("The URL doesn’t exists (more specifically isn’t reachable).");
});
$headers = get_headers($url);
restore_error_handler();

// String comparisons should be made with ==
if (!isset($headers[0]) || substr($headers[0], 9, 3) != "200") {
  throw new LogicException("The URL doesn’t exists (more specifically isn’t reachable).");
}

?>
```

Comment: Kool, I need to wait for new PC until I can test this, thx for the feedback.